# Bootstrap Layout Problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a login page with Twitter's Bootstrap, and I have a problem. I can't get a thumbnail to display where I want it to. You can see here: http://metamint.net/login
I want to put a thumbnail in the blank space next to the forms, but it won't work correctly; the forms are pushed down or moved off to the side. How can I do this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any thumbnails on the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems.

1. You put the thumbnail in a row, so it's going to clear all floats.
2. You put the thumbnail first, which doesn't flow well with how bootstrap is set up.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        .... form content here
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        .... thumbnail content here
    </div>
</div>
```